# Change URLs into files (Parse.com using Javascript CloudCode)

Tags: javascript, http, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I need to batch change a number of image links (URL's links that exist within a class in) to image files (that Parse.com hosts).

Cloud code is (apparently) how to do it.

I've followed the documentation [here](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#files) but haven't had any success.

What I wanted to do is:

1. Take URL link from "COLUMN_1"
2. Make it a file
3. Upload file to "COLUMN_1" (overwrite existing URL). If this is dangerous- can upload it to a new column ("COLUMN_2").
4. Repeat for next row

This code did not work (this is my first time with JS):

```
imgFile.save().then(function () {
    object.set("COLUMN_1", imgFile);
    return object.save();
}).then(function (CLASSNAME) {
    response.success("saved object");
}, function (error) {
   response.error("failed to save object");
});
```

Can anyone recommend how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK- this successfully works for anyone else trying.

```
    Parse.Cloud.job("convertFiles", function(request, status) { //Cuts the rundata out of poor runs
    function sleep(milliseconds) {
      var start = new Date().getTime();
      for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    // Tell the JS cloud code to keep a log of where it's upto. Manually create one row (in class "debugclass") to get an object Id
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var Debug = Parse.Object.extend("debugclass");
    var queryForDebugObj = new Parse.Query(Debug);
    queryForDebugObj.equalTo("objectId", "KbwwDV2S57");

    // Query for all users
    // var queryForSublist = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend("gentest"));


    queryForDebugObj.find({
        success: function(results) {
            var debugObj = results[0];

            var processCallback = function(res) {
                    var entry = res[0];
                    var debugObj = results[0];
                    debugObj.set("LastObject", entry.id);
                    debugObj.save();

                    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                        url: entry.get("smallImage2"),
                        method: "GET",
                        success: function(httpImgFile) 
                        {
                            console.log("httpImgFile: " + String(httpImgFile.buffer));
                            var imgFile = new Parse.File("picture.jpg", {base64: httpImgFile.buffer.toString('base64')});

                            imgFile.save().then(function () {
                                console.log("2");
                                entry.set("smallImage1", imgFile);
                                entry.save(null, {
                                  success: function(unused) {
                                    debugObj.increment("itemDone");
                                    sleep(20);
                                    res.shift();
                                    if (res.length === 0) {
                                        process(entry.id);
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        processCallback(res);
                                    }


                                  },
                                  error: function(unused, error) {
                                    response.error("failed to save entry");
                                  }
                                });    
                            });                                             
                        },
                        error: function(httpResponse) 
                        {
                            console.log("unsuccessful http request");
                            response.error(responseString);
                        }
                    });
            };
            var process = function(skip) {{
                var queryForSublist = new Parse.Query("genpants");

                if (skip) {
                    queryForSublist.greaterThan("objectId", skip);
                    console.error("last object retrieved:" + skip);
                }
                queryForSublist.ascending("objectId");
                queryForSublist.find().then(function querySuccess(res) {
                    processCallback(res);
                }, function queryFailed(reason) {
                    status.error("query unsuccessful, length of result " + result.length + ", error:" + error.code + " " + error.message);
                });
            }};

            process(debugObj.get("LastObject"));

        },
        error: function(error) {
            status.error("xxx Uh oh, something went wrong 2:" + error + "  " + error.message);
        }
    });  
});
```